# Selenium-getfirstselectedoption method too slow

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am using getfirstselectedoption.gettext() method to get the default selected value in drop down which helps to reduce execution time as i need to select the value in that drop down every time. But it's taking approx 15 to 20 secs to get that default selected value. Drop down contains nearly 180 string values. I don't understand why it's taking that much time. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the [Selenium API](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/index.html?org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html), and [associated source](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.java) tells you: `.getFirstSelectedOption()` is:

```
public WebElement getFirstSelectedOption() {
    for (WebElement option : getOptions()) {
        if (option.isSelected()) {
            return option;
        }
    }
    throw new NoSuchElementException("No options are selected");
}
```

and `getOptions()` is:

```
/**
 * @return All options belonging to this select tag
 */
public List<WebElement> getOptions() {
    return element.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
}
```

So your expectation that at the first hit the loop will stop is not correct; it has to fetch all your options first.